# Move vBulletin to subdomain or to a folder?

Tags: subdomain, transfer, vbulletin, folder

I've a quite big vBulletin forum, with 400'000 messages and 15'000 users. Now I want to disable the vBulletin CMS and install Wordpress in the root of my domain.

So I'll move the forum in a folder (mysite.it/forum/) or in a subdomain (forum.mysite.it). Which is the best solution according to your experience?
What do you suggest me to do?
Thanks.

Comment: It is about *your* preference of how you want your website structure setup. You can have it eithe or and a combination of both.

Comment: @Fluorocarbon what about SEO, according to you?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to keep your page-rank for SEO or not. If you switch to a subdomain you will get a huge hit on your PR as subdomains are treated separately from main domains.

For this reason, I would have it in a subfolder. There is no one stopping you from doing a 301 redirect from subdomain to subfolder, so you will be able to access via both.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I'm trying to study the best solution possibile for SEO. I made some research on google and I found that people are suggesting to use a subdomain for seo reasons if the forum is quite big. Now you're suggesting me to use a subfolder, so I'm totally confused :D Let's assume that I'm starting from 0, and my forum has 0 messages and 0 members, would you suggest to put it in a subfolder or in a subdomain?

Comment: You have to keep in mind that these people's suggestions are for creating a new forum. You already have your forum on main domain with PR etc., thus moving it is a bit different. You still need to think that you will need to redirect all the old URL's to either a subdomain or subdirectory URLs if you do not want penalty.

Comment: Yes I've tried to think to a way to 301 redirect my links, but unfortunatly I don't think that it's possible. This is where I explain the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510647/mass-301-redirection-from-htaccess I can create manual redirects for the 300 articles I've on vBulletin CMS to Wordpress articles, but about the forum I think that the only possibile solution is to 301 redirect only the most important topics and category. Really I don't know what to do, but I'm forced to move from vBulletin CMS to Wordpress as I think that VB CMS it terrible for SEO.